# How IoT Cryptocurrency?

Tags: iota-network

I am working on IoT (Azure IoT platform) since long time but there is first requirement came for managing cryptocurrency using IoT. in past we only did managing the temperature, logistics tracking etc. means in short managing the Things we have used IoT but I am very curious to know how can IoT helps in cryptocurrency?

Answer (score 1):

There are really massive usecases for immutable data transport with a protocoll like IOTA. Have a look here, it introduces a Project that Dell, Intel and IOTA are working on for IOT https://blog.iota.org/together-iota-and-dell-technologies-demonstrate-project-alvarium/ - You will also find the link for the live demonstration webinar here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltv7E0fJBWI
Further you could look into this project, they integrate IOT devices and controllers with IOTA already https://iot2tangle.io/hub.html
And just found this:
https://assets.cdn.sap.com/sapcom/docs/2020/03/08753263-887d-0010-87a3-c30de2ffd8ff.pdf

And the other big thing are of course direct micropayments. So think about your sensor collects data and this data is used by a customers - with IOTA you can establish pay per use cases without any administrative overhead. Your customer directly pays and receives data using IOTA.
All data collection transport and value distribution can be done in a fully decentralized, immutable and trustless way.

I would strongly recommend you to visit IOTA's Discord, where a much bigger community and especially all IOTA Developers and Iota Foundation members are daily online and available to answer all your questions much more specific than i am able to do this here:
https://discord.iota.org/

Comment: This seems also a very interesting paper:
https://pure.hud.ac.uk/ws/portalfiles/portal/19558445/Enabling_Distributed_Intelligence_in_the_Internet_of_Things_with_IOTA_and_Mobile_Agents.pdf